# change years in datetime array to current year

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

How can I change year component to 2021 in all `datetime` values using `lubridate`?

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

time <- ymd_hms(c("2018-01-05 12:00:15", "2018-01-01 02:00:15", "2018-02-25 12:00:15", 
                  "2018-04-15 12:00:15", "2020-10-15 12:00:15", "2019-10-20 12:00:15",
                  "2019-11-15 12:01:15", "2018-11-02 11:00:15", "2018-07-09 02:00:15",
                  "2020-10-02 11:00:15", "2020-01-29 12:00:15", "2019-03-15 12:00:15")
                )

tbl <- tibble(time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
year(tbl$time) = 2021


> tbl
# A tibble: 12 × 1
   time               
   <dttm>             
 1 2021-01-05 12:00:15
 2 2021-01-01 02:00:15
 3 2021-02-25 12:00:15
 4 2021-04-15 12:00:15
 5 2021-10-15 12:00:15
 6 2021-10-20 12:00:15
 7 2021-11-15 12:01:15
 8 2021-11-02 11:00:15
 9 2021-07-09 02:00:15
10 2021-10-02 11:00:15
11 2021-01-29 12:00:15
12 2021-03-15 12:00:15
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very simple!

Comment: how do you write this inside `mutate()` i.e. `tbl %>% mutate(time2 = )`

Comment: Is this what you want? `tbl %>% mutate(time2 = \`year<-\`(time, 2021))`